# Javascript regex extract with variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'd like to extract values from below key:value pairs being sent in as a single string:

```
"var1:value1,var2:value2,var3:value3"
```

I have to use JavaScript and unfortunately I am unable to use an array and loop through the var1,var2,var3 keys due to the regex unable to handle variables... I am wondering if there is a way to do this in JS?

See below:

```
function onBefore(current, previous) 
{
if (current.key != '' || current.key != null) 
{
    if (current.key.match(/var1/)) {
    var assign = current.key.match(/(?:var1:)([^,]+)/)[1];
    } else if (current.key.match(/var2/)) {
    var assign = current.key.match(/(?:var2:)([^,]+)/)[1];
    } else if (current.key.match(/var3/)) {
    var assign = current.key.match(/(?:var3:)([^,]+)/)[1];
    } else if (current.key.match(/var4/)) {
    var assign = current.key.match(/(?:var4:)([^,]+)/)[1];
    }
    } else {
        assign = "None";
    }
    if (assign != "None") {
    current.node = assign;
    }
}
}
```

@revo thanks for that answer, for others to benefit... here's the final code:

```js
 var str = "keyIcareabout:test3end,something:value,nothing:burger";
 var node = "None";
 
 function valueOf(key) {
    return (m = (new RegExp("\\b" + key + ":([^,]+)")).exec(str)) !== null ? m[1] : null;
 }
 
 if (str != '' || str !== null) 
 {
  var resources = ["keyIcareabout","somethingelseIcareabout"];
  
  for (i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) 
  {
   if (str.match(resources[i])) 
   {
    node = valueOf(resources[i]);
   }
  }
  
 }
 
 if (node != "None") 
 {
  console.log("Matched " + node + " with node field ");
 }
```

Comment: Split it by commas, and then split by colons?

Comment: *due to the regex unable to handle variables* — what does that mean?

Comment: Ok, so may the sample string I provided didn't do judgement to what I am actually dealing with....

    xrandom1:xkey1,xrandom2:ykey2,var1:value1,xrandom3:xkey3
    yrandom1:ykey1,yrandom2:ykey2,var2:value2,rxandom3:ykey3


    And I am only interested in value1 if var1 exists... it may not exist at all... the comment about regex unable to handle variables, i.e. due to the 'extraction', I had to use the ?:xyz: argument which doesn't support variables... or at least doesn't work if I use an array variable to substitute

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.split`:

```js
const data = 'var1:value1,var2:value2,var3:value3';
const pairStrings = data.split(/,/g);
const pairs = pairStrings.map(pairString => pairString.split(/:/));
const object = pairs.reduce((object, [key, value]) => {
  object[key] = value;
  return object;
}, {});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You underestimated RegEx. Your whole function could be shorten to this:

```
function valueOf(key) {
   return (m = (new RegExp("\\b" + key + ":([^,]+)")).exec(str)) !== null ? m[1] : null;
}
```

You don't have to check for each key individually in an if condition. Pass `key` to above `valueOf()` function to retrieve the value.

```js
var str = "aws_acnt_name:test,aws_acnt_num:1234," +
   "host:identity01.auth-test,region:us-west-2,snow_sg:aws_cloud";

function valueOf(key) {
   return (m = (new RegExp("\\b" + key + ":([^,]+)")).exec(str)) !== null ? m[1] : null;
}

console.log(valueOf('host'));
console.log(valueOf('aws_acnt_name'));
```

Comment: Sry, the actual var1,var2,var3 is completely different... I just mentioned those as an example... in reality, this would be completely different strings...

Comment: there is none, it's actual AWS resource tags... it could be loadbalancername or autoscale_group, etc. i.e. no pattern...

Comment: So you have multiple `key:value` pairs in one single input string that you want to capture each key and corresponding value? @DragonYoon

Comment: Yeah, so here is a real example:

aws_acnt_name:test,aws_acnt_num:1234,host:identity01.auth-test,region:us-west-2,snow_sg:aws_cloud


In there I only want to capture "identity01.auth-test" if the tag "host" exists in the string.

Comment: You are doing it right as I see in your question `str.match(/host:([^,]+)/)[1]`. What's your main problem? @DragonYoon

Comment: I was hoping I don't have to repeat code this way... instead wanted to store all the "keys" as array and loop through the assignment... Note that this function will process a string that will only match one of the var1 or var2/3, etc. at any one time... I have a 123 types :( so that's a 123 if/else statements... that can't be right, I am not privy to JS but in other languages I wouldn't dream of doing this...

Comment: Added a live demo to answer. @DragonYoon

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to loop through matches of key/value pairs, and extract the key and value to an object (or an array):

```js
var str = 'var1:value1,var2:value2,var3:value3';

var pattern = /([^:,]+):([^,]+)/g;
var obj = {};
var temp;

while(temp = pattern.exec(str)) {
  obj[temp[1]] = temp[2];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit- deleting my answer as suggested by vasan, we need to have quotes around the key and values. Rather than adding quotes and then parsing it will  be better to just split it using split function. So SimpleJ's answer should work.

Comment: Did you run this? It would't work. You also need to put quotes around all the keys and values. Very hacky.